# how can i upgrade laravel project from version 9.52.8 to 10

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, upgrade

I want to update Laravel from `9.52.8` version to `10`. How do I do that without having to re-download a new project?

This is the `composer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^6.3",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.28",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^10.5",
        "spatie/laravel-query-builder": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
```

Comment: You have to go to the documentation and read it. There is a specific section related to upgrading from the previous version (`9.x`) to the newest one (`10.x`): https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade. You do not have to download a new project, just follow it

Answer (score 4):

- depend on laravel documentation " https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade "

Quick advice to upgrade, change your dependency to be like this :

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
    "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^6.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.7",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.13",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.28",
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^10.7",
    "spatie/laravel-query-builder": "^5.2"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.12",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.22",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.5",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.2",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.1"
  }
```

then remove fruitcake/laravel-cors package from your project becuase this package added to laravel core dependency .
add expire at column to sanctum table.
upgrade your php version to 8.1 .
check the used packages like "bensampo/laravel-enum" to be sure available to laravel 10 or not.